# How to find published data with the article?

Tags: star, data-analysis, raw-data

How to find data published with an article, please? For instance, let us consider this [paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1994A%26AS..108..237M/abstract). There are data products and the link to SIMBAD on the right. Then, the table with objects appears, but there is only one record of magnitude for all objects. Where to find times against magnitudes, please?

Comment: if the raw data is not public, you probably have to ask the authors directly

Comment: Data taken at La Silla should be available in the ESO archive.

Comment: @ProfRob Since those were photometer data taken in the late 1980s and early 1990s, they're probably *not* in the ESO archive (e.g., no FITS files were recorded). A search for HD 142983 (the star with the most observations in the paper) shows nothing earlier than 2001 available in the archive.

Comment: Thank you very much